# sql server 2000 error, error trying to connect to sql server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2000

i am connecting to sql server 2000 on a remote computer with a dotnet application, but when i try to open the connection it gives the following error:

> When connecting to SQL Server 2005, this failure may be caused by the fact that under the default settings SQL Server does not allow remote connections

What is this?

Answer (score 0):

It means that the remote SQL server is configured to not allow remote connections.

From [this](http://forums.asp.net/p/1209227/2542777.aspx#2542777) forum discussion:

1. Make sure SQL SERVER is up and the instance you try to connect is running.
2. Your system Firewall should not block SQL Server port.
3. Go to Computer Management >> Service and Application >> SQL Server 2005 Configuration >> Network Configuration Enable TCP/IP protocol. Make sure that SQL SERVER port is by Default 1433.
4. Now follow [this](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;914277) KB Article of MSDN depending on your server.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you're connecting to a sql server 2000 instance?
Possibly it's been upgraded to 2005?

Try following the procedure here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/914277 to allow remote connections.

Answer (score -1):

By default, as a security feature, SQL Server 2005 does not enable connections from other machines on the network.

Verify that your SQL Server and its databases are suitably secured (for example, have proper user accounts and passwords, etc.). Once you are satisfied, go to Start, Program Files, Microsoft SQL Server 2005, Configuration Tools, SQL Server Surface Area Configuration. Look for Database Engine, Remote Connections and change the setting to allow remote connections.

Comment: But he said that he is running SQL Server 2000, not 2005!

Comment: <But he said that he is running SQL Server 2000> See the error message also posted. The error message clearly is from SQL Server 2005.

Comment: @Jaywalker you're write, we never had 2005 installed on our servers. Thanks anyway